# SQL semantics differences moving a table from FROM to INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

[update] Every `account_id` in any of the tables has a matching row in `AccountList`, which is why I'm stumped. [/update]

I have a longer query with very different output depending on the join order, which is not unusual, but in this case I cannot understand why the semantics differ for putting a table directly in the FROM vs putting that same table in an INNER JOIN at the end.

Putting AccountList in the FROM produces incorrect results in my final output:

```
FROM
  AccountList
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Yeti
  USING (account_id)
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Snowman
  USING (date, account_id)
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Goose
  USING (date, account_id)
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Flowers
  USING (date, account_id)
INNER JOIN
  Dates
  USING (date);
```

Moving it to the end and INNER JOINing it produces the correct result set:

```
FROM
  Yeti
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Snowman
  USING (date, account_id)
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Goose
  USING (date, account_id)
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Flowers
  USING (date, account_id)
INNER JOIN
  Dates
  USING (date)
INNER JOIN
  AccountList
  USING (account_id);
```

Here's that same diff side by side:
[image: Here's that same diff side by side]

Any thoughts? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Different queries. What's the question?

Comment: `FULL JOIN` is basically the horizontal equivalent of a `UNION` so the second query associates and inner joins `AccountList` with `Dates` and `Flowers`

Comment: How do you define "correct result set"?

Comment: How do the results differ? (You should have an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the queries in order to compare the results.)

Comment: What is your DBMS? There is no `date` column in `AccountList` I guess? Otherwise you should get an abiguity error, but if the table does have that column and your DBMS fails to throw an error, that would explain different results.

Comment: Syntax is GoogleSql, running on F1. Correct, `AccountList` does not contain a `date` column, otherwise my query engine would indeed throw an error.

Comment: You still haven't told us how the two results are different. Does one result contain a row that the other does not? If so: What does that row look like? Do you expect this row in the results or not?

Answer (score 3):

You have to look not at the tables, but at the joins between them.

In your first query, all of the joins which reference the `account_id` column are `FULL OUTER JOIN`s:

- AccountList to Yeti
- AccountList+Yeti to Snowman
- AccountList+Yeti+Snowman to Goose
- AccountList+Yeti+Snowman+Goose to Flowers

So all five of (AccountList, Yeti, Snowman, Goose, Flowers) could have completely non-overlapping values for `account_id`, and the rows would be included anyway.

In your second query, there are three using `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

- Yeti to Snowman
- Yeti+Snowman to Goose
- Yeti+Snowman+Goose to Flowers

So all four of (Yeti, Snowman, Goose, Flowers) can still have completely non-overlapping values for `account_id`.

But then the last one uses `INNER JOIN`:

- Yeti+Snowman+Goose+Flowers to AccountList

That means that rows will be excluded if they don't match:

- any value for `account_id` which appears in `AccountList` but doesn't appear in at least one of (Yeti, Snowman, Goose, Flowers)
- any value for `account_id` which appears in at least one of (Yeti, Snowman, Goose, Flowers) but doesn't appear in `AccountList`

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that there is no `account_id` in any of the tables without a matching row in `AccountList`. I will update the question to say so.

Comment: @SethElliott A better idea would be to produce an [mcve] and actually explains what results you're getting, and what you expected. Otherwise, there could be any number of "wrong" guesses like this explaining true but perhaps not relevant differences between the queries.